# Primefaces sorting only works after filtering

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm pretty new to JSF development and Primefaces. My problem is that I get listed the data in the datatable but the data doesn't get sorted when clicked at the arrows. If you filter the datatable then click on the arrows everything is fine. 
Any hints?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:body>
    <h:link value="INSERT NEW Customer" outcome="/kunde/insert" />
    <h:form id="form">
        <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />
        <p:dataTable widgetVar="kundeTable" var="kunde" value="#
{kundeController.findAll()}" lazy="false">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:outputPanel>
                    <h:outputText value="Search all fields" />
                    <h:inputText id="globalFilter" 
onkeyup="PF('kundeTable').filter()" />
                </p:outputPanel>
            </f:facet>

            <p:column sortBy="#{kunde.id}" filterBy="#{kunde.id}">
                <f:facet name="header">Id</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{kunde.id}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="#{kunde.name}" filterBy="#{kunde.name}" >
                <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{kunde.name}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column sortBy="#{kunde.strasse}" filterBy="#{kunde.strasse}" >
                <f:facet name="header">Strasse</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{kunde.strasse}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column sortBy="#{kunde.plz}" filterBy="#{kunde.plz}" >
                <f:facet name="header">Plz</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{kunde.plz}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column sortBy="#{kunde.ort}" filterBy="#{kunde.ort}" >
                <f:facet name="header">Ort</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{kunde.ort}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">DELETE</f:facet>
                <h:commandLink value="Löschen" action="#{kundeController.delete(kunde)}" onclick="return confirm('Wollen Sie wirklich diese Person löschen?')" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">UPDATE</f:facet>
                <h:commandLink value="Bearbeiten" action="#{kundeController.update(kunde)}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Hi, yes my hint would be to read [ask] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and [mcve] and improve your question.

Comment: @LupoZ, please add the html part referring to the datatable and the version of jsf / primefaces that your are using

Comment: @ Maciej Kowalski Yeah I did now. Sorry for not being precise.

Comment: Seems to me you need a h:head above h:body

Comment: Before filtering.. can you sort at all? i mean after you click few times on the arrows? Or only after a filter action?

Comment: @Maciej Kowalski Only after Filter action...

Comment: Do you get any errors in the javascript console upon sorting?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. As a workaround you can call the filter function of the table once after page load:

```
            <p:remoteCommand autoRun="true" oncomplete="PF('kundeTable').filter();" />
```

Place that after the `</p:dataTable>` closing tag.